# Purpose of gamma multiplier in gradient boosting

Tags: gradient-descent, boosting

looking through the mathematics of gradient boosting on the relevant [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_boosting), intuitively what is the purpose of the multiplier $\gamma_i$?

[image]

This term does not appear in the following definition of $F_m(x)$

[image]

But confusingly, then appers in the subsequent definition:

[image]

Any advice appreciated, thanks.

Comment: you may see this: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/472766/question-about-step-size-in-gradient-boosting